# private hosting custom domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, host

I just bought a domain name but not hosting services.The domain is [www.asteriosharitos.com](http://www.asteriosharitos.com)

I now am running a site on wordpress on my localhost with mamp! can anyone tell me 
   how I publish this site to MY domain name and host it from my computer with mamp or with anything else but free?

I say free because it is my first time and the site is for fun only!

thank you!

Comment: If you have a public IP address given to your computer by the internet service provider then you could set the DNS name to the IP address given for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some free hosting, like firebase for example, which are allow to set up your own domain name after it verification.

Answer (score 0):

If it is "just for fun" as you say, you can host it on your computer. Create a Host A record for the domain that points to your external IP. Then make sure you have port 443 or 80 open (depending on whether or not you are using SSL).

Another Option: If you google "Free Wordpress Hosting", You will also find hosting providers that will host it for you.